# How to execute command in bash / php script?

Tags: php, html, linux, bash, server

I am super new to web server developing and I have this server in which I want to run a bash script on a PHP script. Basically, I have this HTML file and when I click this button, it opens a online terminal, courtesy of `ttyd`. To start the terminal, I have to run:

```
ttyd -p 8080 bash
```

So far this is in my HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <form action="/terminal/terminal.php">
            <input type="submit" value="Server Command Line Terminal">
        </form>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

My PHP script is shown here:

```
<?php
shell_exec("/var/www/html/terminal/ttyd-terminal.sh");
sleep(1);
header('Location: http://10.0.0.199:8080');
?>
```

And this is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

eval 'ttyd -p 8080 bash'
```

So far, when I go to the site, the terminal will not open, I have tried many solutions and none them have worked, I just get a timed out response from the server, I have also tried `echo 'ttyd -p 8080 bash'` but that does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the bash script. For anybody who wants to make a `.sh` script executable, do the following:

```
chmod +x file.sh
```

This solved my problem and now everything works fine.